# Disable all tooltips in MATLAB editor

Tags: matlab, popup, tooltip, warnings

I'm using MATLAB on a server via ssh access (OPENGL rendering). When I'm editing the code it is extremely annoying, that eg. on mouseover a warning or editing a variable that appears several times in the code a tooltip pops up!

Because in this setup it appears as an extra window, and the connection crashes, when I try to close it.

Does anyone of you know how to disable especially the warning popups without losing the yellow underlining of warnings?

Here a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, you can't turn this functionality off. You might be able to try a different X server? I've heard that using mobaXterm has fixed some problems that people have had with MATLAB over ssh.

Comment: Thank you, but for this I have to rely on powerful university resources, so I have not the option to use a different server.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The X-server is the local program that is being used to display the MATLAB environment being run on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the popups, but you'll lose the interactive underlining in the MATLAB Editor.

To disable the popups, got to Preferences->Code Analyzer, and uncheck the option "Enable integrated warning and error messages".

Even though you'll lose the interactive underlinings in the MATLAB Editor, you can still use the Code Analyzer directly.

If you save your file and then type `checkcode myfile.m`, the Code Analyzer will run, and show you the places at which you would have had underlinings in the editor.